# Correct way for writing HTML tags in posts -- "<div>" or just "div"?

Tags: discussion

When asking or answering, should I write HTML tags like this:

> Put your image into `<div>` tag.

("*Put your image into `<div>` tag*" -- if written in inline text)

or like that:

> Put your image into `div` tag.

("*Put your image into `div` tag*").

I know, that this is a very simple problem and many may simply ignore it. But I seen both ways of writing this and would like to know, what is an "official canon" for that?

**EDIT**: I'm asking about editing other users' posts. I don't want to make "improper" change when fixing others questions or answers.

Comment: I don't think there's really an official policy on this - unless you're writing actual HTML, neither is "wrong". Describing it as a "problem" at all, even a simple one, is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Slow day? I tend to say "the `<div>` *tag*" but "the `div` *element*" and I consider this more correct than the other way around. However, I would not be surprised if you found that I'm not consistent in my posts. I've decided that worrying about this is not worth my time.

Comment: This isn't an entirely worthless discussion, but unless you're asking about editing other users' posts, I don't see how it's a *meta* discussion.

Comment: @AirThomas I'm exactly asking asking about editing other users' posts. What could be the other reason for asking such question? :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the element, the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) says

> The `div` element

However, if you refer to the [start tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags) or [end tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags), they include the `<` and `>` characters.